# Unwanted card shadow on android 4.2.2

Tags: android, cardview, android-elevation

I implemented a `LisView` that has nested card views with a custom `ImageView` for the shadow. Here's the layout :

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/food_card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

(... views here ...)

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The problem is that the CardView shows has an elevation value on some devices, even if `card_view:cardElevation="0dp"` is set to `0dp`.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using CardView if you dont want the shadow effect? That is the whole point of card view

Comment: You're right, I missed some steps ahah. I mean, I first implemented the RecyclerView and then changed to ListView because of some problems with recycling the items and I didn't realize that I simply could delete the CardView and replace it with a normal layout. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by deleting the `CardView` from the layout and inflating directly the `LinearLayout` that holds the item list view.